# How do I change the code so that the 0 text operand is not visible only in between entering numbers and operators?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm using android studio so I'm not sure if I change the attributes linked to the xml files or in the MainActivity.java file. I tried to change the color of the text to be the same as the background so 0 would appear invisible but would get insufficient color contrast warnings. If i set that same text view to a transparent color I also get the same warning message.

```
package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Task 1: Declare UI objects to be referenced
private TextView mNumberDisplay;

//Task 2: Declare variables to compute calculations

private SimpleExpression mExpression;

private TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    //Task 3: Get reference to the UI component (TextView)
    mNumberDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //Task 4: Create the data Model for storing numbers
    //and calculating the result
    mExpression = new SimpleExpression();
    }

    //When the AC button is clicked
    public void goAC (View view) {
        //display 0
        mNumberDisplay.setText("0");
        //initialize both operands to 0 in data Model
        mExpression.clearOperands();
    }

        //When the digit button is clicked, display the number
        public void goOperand (View view) {
        //Get the value that is displayed in TextView1
        String val = (String) mNumberDisplay.getText();
        //Get the single digit that is clicked from the button
        String digit = (String) view.getContentDescription();
        //If the value that is displayed in TextView1
        //is a single digit and 0 and a button is clicked
        //Then display the single digit
        //Else when there is more than a single digit
        //Then append what is displayed in TextView1
        //to the single digit that is clicked
        if (val.equals("0")) {
        mNumberDisplay.setText(digit);
        } else {
        mNumberDisplay.setText(String.format("%s%s", mNumberDisplay.getText(),digit));  
        }
        }
        //When the operator button is clicked
       public void goOperator (View view) {
       //Get the operator that is clicked from the button
       String operator = (String) view.getContentDescription();

      //Get operand1 (String) that is displayed in TextView1
      String val = (String) mNumberDisplay.getText();
      //Convert the String to an Integer
      //and send operand1 to the data Model
      mExpression.setOperand1(Integer.parseInt(val));

      //Send operator to data Model
      mExpression.setOperator(operator);

      //Display 0 in TextView1 to get ready to take in Operand2
      mNumberDisplay.setText("0");
    }

    //When the = button is clicked, display result
    public void goCompute (View view) {
    //Get operand2 (String) that is displayed in TextView1
    String val = (String) mNumberDisplay.getText();
    //Convert the String to an Integer
    //and send operand2 to the data Model
    mExpression.setOperand2(Integer.parseInt(val));

    //Display the result in TextView1 by calling getValue()
    //then converting (int)getValue into a String
    mNumberDisplay.setText(String.format("%s", mExpression.getValue()));

    }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Please add xml file, SimpleExpression library and error screenshot